# PXDBIntList or PXDBStringList - where condition?

Tags: acumatica

Trying to build a drop down list from a table, but only need rows that match a specific criteria.

Is it possible to limit the values that go into a `PXDBIntList` or `PXDBStringList` attribute, much like applying a `where` condition?

Or, would I be better off switching to something like a control with a selector?

Answer (score 0):

Use a drop-down list to display a list of constants.

Use a selector to display records coming from a DAC.

If you need to manipulate the content of a drop-down list you can use `PXStringListAttribute.SetList` or `PXIntListAttribute.SetList` methods.

Based on your question, you should use a selector control with a where clause. This is a common pattern across the platform.

Example of workgroup selector filtered by logged in user:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<TM.EPCompanyTree.workGroupID,
    Where<TM.EPCompanyTree.workGroupID, TM.Owned<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>)))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.